# Not sure whether to use inheritance when trying to extend my stack function

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack, nodes

I wrote a stack before. Basically, I had two classes, Node and Stack. This stack can just push, pop and check the head of the stack. The code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class Datatype>
class Node
{
    public:
        Node()
        {
            next = NULL;
            prev = NULL;
        }
        Node* getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }
        Node* getPrev()
        {
            return prev;
        }
        Datatype* getData()
        {
            return &data;
        }
        void changeNext()
        {
            next = NULL;
        }
        void changeNext(Node& nextNode)
        {
            next = &nextNode;
        }
        void changePrev()
        {
            prev = NULL;
        }
        void changePrev(Node& prevNode)
        {
            prev = &prevNode;
        }
        Node* addNext(Node &);
        Node* addPrev(Node &);
        void nodeDel();
        void addData(Datatype &);
    private:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        Datatype data;
};

template<class Datatype>
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack() : head( NULL )
        {

        }
        int push(Datatype &);
        int pop(Datatype &);
        Datatype* peek();
    private:
        Node<Datatype> *head;
};

template <class Datatype>
Node<Datatype>* Node<Datatype>::addNext(Node<Datatype>& exi_node)
{
    if (exi_node.getNext() == NULL)
    {
        changePrev(exi_node);
        exi_node.changeNext(*this);
    }
    else
    {
        Node* next = exi_node.getNext();
        changePrev(exi_node);
        changeNext(*next);
        exi_node.changeNext(*this);
        next -> changePrev(*this);
    }
    return &exi_node;
}

template <class Datatype>
Node<Datatype>* Node<Datatype>::addPrev(Node<Datatype>& exi_node)
{
    if (exi_node.getPrev() == NULL)
    {
        changeNext(exi_node);
        exi_node.changePrev(*this);
    }
    else
    {
        Node* prev = exi_node.getPrev();
        changePrev(*prev);
        changeNext(exi_node);
        exi_node.changePrev(*this);
        prev -> changeNext(*this);
    }
    return &exi_node;
}

template<class Datatype>
void Node<Datatype>::nodeDel()
{
    if (prev == NULL && next == NULL)
        ;
    else if (prev == NULL)
    {
        Node* next = getNext();
        next -> changePrev();
    }
    else if (next == NULL)
    {
        Node* prev = getPrev();
        prev -> changeNext();
    }
    else
    {
        Node* next = getNext();
        Node* prev = getPrev();
        next -> changePrev(*prev);
        prev -> changeNext(*next);  
    }
    delete this;
    return;
}

template <class Datatype>
void Node<Datatype>::addData(Datatype &new_data)
{
    data = new_data;
}

template <class Datatype>
int Stack<Datatype>::push(Datatype &new_data)
{
    Node<Datatype> *pt_node = new Node<Datatype>;
    if (pt_node == NULL)
        return -1;

    pt_node -> addData(new_data);

    if (head == NULL)
        head = pt_node;
    else
    {
        pt_node -> addPrev(*head);
        head = pt_node;
    }

    cout << *(head -> getData()) << endl;

    return 0;
}

template <class Datatype>
int Stack<Datatype>::pop(Datatype &pop_data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return 0;

    pop_data = *(head -> getData());

    if (head -> getNext() == NULL)
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<Datatype>* temp = head;
        head = head -> getNext();
        delete temp;
    }

    return 1;
}

template <class Datatype>
Datatype* Stack<Datatype>::peek()
{
    return (this->head)->getData();
}
```

It's a pretty simple stack. The Stack class has some interface for users and also a pointer points to the first Node. Node class has two pointers pointing to both direction and also a data field.
Now, I want to add a function to my Stack, which is to find the min value in the stack within O(1). One method is to add a field "local_min" in Node class, which records the minimum value beneath itself. In this way, pop(), push(), find_min() can all be done in O(1).
My intuition is to have inheritance of both Node and Stack, because I only need to add a new function. However, I feel this very inconvenient. I have to rewrite almost all the functions. The pointer in both Node and Stack pointed to class Node. If I use a new class, like New_Node, all the thing has to be changed.
Are there any good ways for me to do this extension? I really feel like inheritance should be working well here. However, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: And you are not using `std::stack` because...?

Comment: I am learning C++ and just try to implement a stack myself and do some implementation. From what I learn, I only know put "using namespace std" at the very beginning. I am not sure this std::stack. The code I provide works well. I met problem when I want to do extension.

Comment: notice `Stack` != `stack`; c++ is case sensitive

Comment: @user3352668 You are learning it wrong. You should _not_ put `using namespace std;` at the very beginning. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: @user3352668, may I ask where are you learning C++ exacly? What book/resource?

Comment: did you heard about aspect oriented programming? I think this is the way here. Create a new Stack class that inherit your class and add the new feature in each function, then call the father function to do the stack work.

Comment: *The code I provide works well.* A Stack class with no user-defined destructor to handle the dynamically allocated memory? As soon as you add the destructor, try this: `int main() { Stack<int> s1; int x = 10; s1.push(x); Stack<int> s2 = s1; }` Watch what happens when your program exits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Stack` is not written in a way that facilitates clean OO re-use: you haven't got a virtual destructor, and the member functions that derived types may wish to override aren't virtual either (specifically `push` and `pop`).  So, it is cleaner to write a new class that uses Composition - storing a `Stack` object as a data member.  Then there's no need to change `Node` - you can just add a `Stack<Node*>` to your `StackWithMin` class, and push/pop an extra `Node*` only when the data `Stack` pushes/pops a `Node` that changes the min.  For example, after pushing 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, your `StackWithMin` data members would be:

```
Stack<Data>   Stack<Node*>
[0] 3         &[0]
[1] 7         &[3]
[2] 5
[3] 2
[4] 3
```

This encodes that the current min is at `&[3]`, and if a pop removes that element then it should be popped from the `Stack<Node*>` too.

Separately, `Node` is a supporting type for `Stack`, and the definition need not be offered as part of the client-facing interface.  To hide it, consider putting it in a namespace called something like `Stack_Private`, `Stack_Support` or `Stack_Implementation` so that clients know not to use, then you can reasonably make it a `struct` and get/set the data members directly instead of using accessor functions - that will make your code less verbose.

Comment: "Composition" should be bold, font size 100. I have already seen too much code trying to be as "object oriented" as possible in my life. Especially when using templates, inheritance is often unnecessary.

Comment: Why do I need to virtual those functions that may wish to override?

Comment: Well, say some client code already has a `Stack<int, 100> my_stack;` and calls a function `void add_data(Stack<int, 100>* p) { p->push(10); p->push(20); }`, then you tell everyone you've got a great new version that also tracks the minimum value: the client programmer goes and changes `Stack_With_Min<int, 100> my_stack;` and compiles... no errors - their call to `f(my_stack)` is still valid because by inheriting from `Stack` you're saying that operations via a base-class pointer are legitimate, but sadly the `push` and `pop` done within `f()` aren't virtual so call the `Stack` implementation.

Comment: That implementation doesn't make any effort to track the minimum.  When `f()` returns to the client code and later a call is made to get the minimum, it will likely be wrong, but depending on what you expected it to have done and how carefully you check it could crash (for example, if you depend on there always being a valid pointer to the minimum somewhere that `f()` hadn't populated).

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just a beginner. You help me a lot!Thanks.

Comment: @user3352668: you're welcome.  You're asking good questions - I'm sure you'll progress quickly.  You might like to read about the Liskov Substitution Principle - it is a great guideline for what it should mean to inherit from and customise a base class, though most explanations of it take a bit of effort to understand, it's well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in these situations you should use non-template base class. This base class can implement all functions which aren't depend of a given data type.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : _next(nullptr), _prev(nullptr) {
    }
public:
    Node* getNext() {
        return _next;
    }
    Node* getPrev() {
        return _prev;
    }
    void setNext(Node *node) {
        _next = node;
    }
    void setPrev(Node *node) {
        _prev = node;
    }
private:
    Node* _next;
    Node* _prev;
};

template <typename Value>
class NodeWithType : public Node
{
public:
    NodeWithType() : Node() {
    }
public:
    const Value& getValue() const {
        return _value;
    }
    void setValue(const Value &value) {
        _value = value;
    }

public:
    Value _value;
};
```

Now, the stack class can use the value independent interface. This simplifies everything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. I want to put those basic Node operation, like addNext, addPrev, delete, in the basic Node class, because they are basic operation of nodes and I don't want to put it somewhere else. However, these operations work only on class Node. All the inheritance of Node Class cannot make use of those functions. I don't know how to solve this problem.